# "ban" vs "being banned" for period

Tags: word-choice

I've got a piece of text:

> Mr Rigby pleaded guilty to dangerous driving and was fined £1,080 and
>   ordered to pay a victim surcharge of £108 and costs of £85. In
>   addition to (ban/being banned) for 12 months, he was ordered to take
>   an extended driving test.

Is it correct to use "ban" instead of "being banned"?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to **a ban of** 12 months, he was ordered to take an extended driving test.

Use of above sentence should be correct.

Comment: Even though your sentence may seem to be correct, the layout of the question hints to it being a multiple choice question from some kind of test. Therefore I think your solution is not a valid answer to the question.

Comment: The choice is between "ban" and "being banned" - no other variants, no other modifications. It's an exam question.

Answer (score 0):

[Oxford link](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ban) The definition that fits this case:

> Officially prevent (someone) from doing something.
>   *‘her son was banned for life from the Centre’*

Some examples:

> 1. I ban you from my house.

This means that I prevent you from entering my house.

> 2. I am being banned from my house.

This means that someone is preventing me from entering my house.

---

> Mr Rigby pleaded guilty to dangerous driving and was fined £1,080 and ordered to pay a victim surcharge of £108 and costs of £85. In addition to (ban/being banned) for 12 months, he was ordered to take an extended driving test.

Mr Rigby is not the person who is enforcing the ban. He is the *target* of the ban. Therefore, it would only be correct to say that **Mr Rigby is being banned**.

Comment: But can it be used as a noun, not a verb?

Comment: @AlexWells - If you did use the word *ban* as a noun, you would still have to structure the sentence differently.  You would have to say something like "in addition to *receiving a ban*".  You can't just say "in addition to ban"; that doesn't make any sense.